# Errors when using afl++

Tags: fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

I am trying to familiarize myself with the usage of afl++. I wrote a simple program that should crash due to buffer overflow if argv[1] is too long.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[4];
    
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the crash to be found by afl++ soon but after running for quite sometime, maybe around 2 hours, I don't see any crashes being logged yet.

The command line I used was

```
afl-fuzz -i afl_inputs -o afl_outputs -- ./target_application
```

The program was compiled with

```
CC=afl-clang-fast++ AFL_HARDEN=1 make
```

Interestingly, when I was troubleshooting this issue, I put some ASCII characters in my input file such as just a character "Z" and modified the command line as such `afl-fuzz -i afl_inputs -o afl_outputs -- ./target_application @@` and afl++ will terminate immediately, stating that one of the test cases caused a crash.

Furthermore, I tried to run the application itself with that input file `./target_application ./afl_inputs/input.txt` and `./target_application < ./afl_inputs/z.txt` but it does not crash in both scenarios.

Questions

- What am I doing wrong?
- Since afl++ fuzzes stdin, can I assume that argv[1] should be populated with random values if I did not specify "@@"? Although it does seems like my assumption is wrong.
- Does "@@" means it will read from my input files and place what it read into the command line (from what I read from the documentation, that seems to be the case)?

Answer (score 1):

It ends without results because your command is wrong, and it is not performing any fuzzing.

AFL++ will take the test case from files, thus you need to modify your source code to perform the fuzzing, e.g. Open a file, read it and perform the strcpy with the buffer with the file content. Or, add a gets in order to take the file contents from stdin.
In the first example, the command should be:

```
afl-fuzz -i afl_inputs -o afl_outputs ./target_application @@
```

In the second example:

```
afl-fuzz -i afl_inputs -o afl_outputs ./target_application
```